# Function cypher(unknown, unknown) does not exist in Apache AGE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, apache-age

I am trying to execute a Cypher query on my Apache AGE graph database using the cypher function in PostgreSQL, but I am encountering an error.

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('g1', $$ MATCH (n) return n $$);
```

And here is the error message that I am getting:

```
ERROR:  function cypher(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM cypher('g1', $$ MATCH (n) return n $$);
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have already checked that I have installed the Apache AGE extension and added it to my database, and I am using the correct graph name (g1) in the query.

I double-checked and confirmed that the AGE extension is installed by running this query.

`SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'age';`

How can I resolve this error and successfully execute my Cypher query in Apache AGE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly there is an error in your query, the correct query is

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('<enter_graph_name_here>', $$ MATCH (n) return n $$)
AS (result agtype);
```

The above command will only execute correctly if you have set the search_path as

```
SET search_path to ag_catalog;
```

If you do not set the search_path as above and it is public be default, then modify the first query as

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.cypher('<enter_graph_name_here>', $$ MATCH (n) return n $$)
AS (result agtype);
```

This is because cypher function is present in `ag_catalog` namespace and you need to either set the namespace to `ag_catalog` using `search_path` or prefix all the function names with `ag_catalog.` in all the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the function exists in your PostgreSQL. You can do this by runningthe following command:

```
SELECT proname FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'cypher';
```

If no results are displayed, the definition of the function hasn't been done properly and needs to be redone.

Comment: How do you “redo” the definition? Also, the problem seems solved already. I’m not sure what this answer adds.